# solve $(x+iy)^2= a+ ib$

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

We know that two complex numbers are equal if their imaginary part and real part are equal from that we get this system of equation.
$$\begin{cases} 
x²-y² =a \\
x²+y² =\sqrt{a²+b²}\\
2xy=b 
\end{cases}$$

I tried to isolate one variable at a time with no success. I tried to substitute $x² +y² = 2y² +a $ into second equation in the system then square both sides I ended up with a messy equality.

So my question is what's approach/trick I needed here to solve this?

Comment: You have $y=\frac{b}{2x}$, just put it in the first equation. Then write $x^2=t$ and you will get a quadratic equation which is easy to solve.

Comment: @Dota Aren't you after the square root of $a+bi$?